# I'm looking for displaying of data along with the counts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For displaying data i'm using chips in react js and along with that i want number of data present

```
getChips = params => {
    let tags = params.value.split(',').map(el => {
      return (
          <Chips
            text={el.trim()}  />  

 // to display data


          <TagsMenu limitedSize
               id={params.data.id}
               name={params.data.name} 
               // to display counts, tagsmenu code has been written in separate file
               packageType={params.data.type}
               data={params.value}
          />
    }
}
```

as of now only data is displaying. counts are not displaying how to combine both

looking somewhat like this (abc)+3

Comment: Can you show `TagsMenu Component` code?

Comment: I can share , but i don't think there is a problem with tagsmenu code bcz i have used this piece of code for another task and its working fine.

problem is how to append this tagsmenu  with chips tag.

Comment: const chipClickHandler = () => {
    if (onChipClick) {
      const tagContainer = <div className='tags-menu-container'> {tags}</div>;
      onChipClick({ tags: tagContainer, id, name, packageType });
   
 


  if (limitedSize) {
    return (
      <div className='tags-menu-container-limited-size'>
        {tags.slice(0, 1)}
        {tags.length > 1 && (
          <Chips key='catalog-tag-count'
                 id='catalog-tag-count'
                 text={`+${tags.length - 1}`}
                 onChipClick={chipClickHandler}

Comment: its too lengthy to share, so i have cropped few lines here

Comment: Update your question with the above code. Don't write code in comments section.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask], donot post code in comments instead edit your question again.

Comment: count of what.?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use arr.length to find the number of data present and pass it.

```
getChips = params => {
let tags = params.value.split(',').map((el, key, arr) => {
  return (
      <Chips
        text={el.trim()}  />
```

// to display data

```
      <TagsMenu limitedSize
           id={params.data.id}
           name={params.data.name} 
           count={arr.legth}
           packageType={params.data.type}
           data={params.value}
      />
}
```

}

Comment: you don't need to split again, this is the reason `.map(element, index, array)` has the array param as well.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, since tagsmenu is the piece of code( which i made generic) and other than the parameter which i mentioned in the code i cannot send other parameter, so i cannot pass count parameter here